# Unable to mount actionable to routes

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add ActionCable to my routes.
One guide says to do:

```
/config/routes.rb
...
mount ActionCable.server = '/cable'
...
```

However when I try to do so and run `rails routes`, I get the following error:
`undefined method server=' for ActionCable:Module (NoMethodError) Did you mean?  server`

I have tried looking for an answer to this however I couldn't find anything.

I am trying to do a React - Ruby on Rails class project.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if the syntax changed with rails versions. In the Rails Guides (which you should be using), it [states to use mount in the application.rb file](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#in-app)

```rb
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.action_cable.mount_path = '/websocket'
end
```